# Pi greco(3.14 costant ) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have to write the famous Number 3.14 but i can’t find the right ascii code for it. Well i’ve found some codes likes 277, 244 , 960 but noone ‘ve worked . Any help? 
~CODE FOR WINDOWS 7~

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03C0/index.htm

if you hold the 'alt' key and then type 227 you will get the pi symbol. But it is not included in ASCII set of characters.

Regards

Thomas
[image]

Comment: I Tried this code and also all mantioned in the link for pi but nothing

Comment: are you trying to type it in an editor or do you want to write code that outputs the symbol to console, dialog box, or .... somewhere?

Comment: you will have to use encoding like utf8 that can display chars beyond the ASCII limits

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: you can open the Windows character map (press Windows key, type "char", klick on list entry), search for the pi character and copy paste it into your editor. Works for notepad and notepad++

Comment: Ok, i ve found it thanks. It gives me even a code : U+03C0. I can i use it? When i tra ‘alt’ + ‘character’ Windows make a Bip